# How to access model weights in Tkinter exe file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have generated an Tkinter GUI and generated one exe file that copied model weights.

the weights folder is in the same folder of the myTKcode.py file.

I generate my model as and load weights as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = MyModel()
model.load_weights("weights/MyModelWeights")
```

Now if I use pyinstaller to generate an exe file as below:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data weights;weights myTKcode.py
```

Based on the size of the `myTKcode.exe` file I can say that weights have been added in the `myTKcode.exe`. But when I run the `myTKcode.exe` file, it does not find the weights folder. But if I copy paste the weights folder in the `dist` folder where `myTKcode.exe` is, it works.

**my question is how access the weights stored in the `myTKcode.exe`?**

Comment: Always use absolute paths instead of relative paths. You may need a environment variable or a command line argument sur specify you “working” directory.

Comment: I know that this is a terrible idea but theoretically can't you base 64 encode the weights and hard code them in your program? After that you can just expand them in a temp folder at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked previously and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile).

In brief, for each folder/file an absolute path has to be added to standalone exe file.

as I have a single folder named weights; I simply add the following code to my code:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

then I loaded weights as below;

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = MyModel()
#model.load_weights("weights/MyModelWeights")
weightDir = resource_path("weights") # resource_path get the correct path for weights directory.
model.load_weights(weightDir+"/MyModelWeights")
```

and then simply run `pyinstaller` as below:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data weights;weights myTKcode.py
```